# Preview graphic shape before applying

Tags: c#, shapes

I am looking to create an Outline around my graphical Shape, to show me where I am creating my shape and when I place the shape the outline will disappear leaving only the shape left, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLkGd.jpg) is a concept gif.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

bitmap bm;

if (currItem == Tool.Square)
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);       
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(panel1.BackColor)), e.X ,e.Y, x - e.X, y - e.Y);
    // Canvas is a Picture Box
    Canvas.Invalidate();
    g.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not commenting the code

Comment: Please view the gif, if you are having trouble understanding what I want to do :)

Comment: Please edit your question by pasting in your code and removing the image. An image of code is unsearchable, can't be copied directly into an IDE and is a certain way to recieve a down vote and/or have your question ignored. It was surely more difficult to include an image of it then it was to just copy/paste the text.

Comment: I have now edited it, thank you for the feedback

Comment: nevermind, Uwe Keim re-edited it and phrased it better than I ever could thank you Uwe.

Comment: The code doesn't provide enough info, Where are you doing this?, Inside form's paint or MouseMove? . Please provide more info or paste the full code. It will be easy to answer

Comment: You don't know how to do it at all or you're having issues?. Please rephrase you question accordingly.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, inside of the mouse move

Comment: sorry I was asleep, I am a bit new to asking for help on here so thank you :)